Apply Label Based on Time Range
I have a column with time values (EST) and would like to apply a label for the time that corresponds with each groups 'working hours'. For example, data looks like the below (column K):
created_at
2:11:00 PM
1:39:00 PM
1:23:00 PM
1:01:00 PM
12:31:00 PM
12:01:00 PM
11:17:00 AM
11:10:00 AM
10:32:00 AM
10:13:00 AM
10:02:00 AM
9:56:00 AM
9:52:00 AM
9:20:00 AM
9:13:00 AM
8:49:00 AM
8:12:00 AM
The four labels I have should be:
US (between 12:01 PM - 6 PM EST)
EMEA (between 3 AM - 9:59 AM EST)
Overlap (between 10 AM - 12 PM EST)
After (6:01 PM - 2:59 AM)
I tried a bunch of random solutions that I found in other threads and altered the values (including just doing a count if, and then counting all the instances), including the below:
=COUNTIFS(OR(K4,">=10:00 AM"),(K4, "<=6:00 PM"))
=COUNTIFS(K4, ">=10:00 AM", K4-1, "<=6:00 PM")=1
